# Aggregate rows for specific variable names in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I want to see the aggregate amount for a column for specific variable name-

when I try this code I can see the aggregation for the entire  data frame:

```
 aggregate(x=Top_10$Amount,by=list(Top_10$Customer_Name),FUN=sum)
```

But, I want to see the aggregate amount for a specific customer (that appears in 4 different rows in the data), so I tried this:

```
aggregate(x=Top_10$Amount,by=list(Top_10$Customer_Name[Top_10$Customer_Name=="abc"]),FUN=sum)
```

But I get this error: Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) :
arguments must have same length

How can it be fixed?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's essential to share a reproducible piece of your data with `dput(head(data))` so that others can use it and have a clear idea of what your data set looks like.

Comment: The data includes only customer names and amounts, some costumers appear in the data multiple times with different amounts, and I want to see the aggregated amount for each customer.